# netrw bug? cannot copy marked file to target

Tags: netrw

When I try to do the following on Windows 10:

1. go to a directory, set it as the target directory using `mt`
2. go to a different directory, mark a file in that directory using `mf`
3. use `mc` to copy the file to the target directory

I get the following error:

```
(netrw) tried using g:netrw_localcopycmd<C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe>; it doesn't work!
```

Is there a fix to this? Or am I doing it wrong?

EDIT:

The output of `:echo g:netrw_localcopycmd` is `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you hit [edit] and put the output of `:echo g:netrw_localcopycmd` ?

Comment: Thank you :) I just added the output of that command.